# Return all unique permutations of possibly-repeating array elements

Tags: arrays, matlab, permutation, combinatorics, built-in

Let's say I have an array of length `N` with `M` different object (`M < N`) so that some of these objects repeat `N_i ... N_M` times. I'd like to find all possible *unique* dispositions (like, arrangements) of the elements of such arrays without computing the entire list of permutations beforehand (both for time and memory constraints).

Of course, the naive solution would be to use `perms` to generate all possible permutations, and then select the unique ones:

```
A = [1, 1, 2];

all_perms = perms(A)
    % all_perms =

    % 2     1     1
    % 2     1     1
    % 1     2     1
    % 1     1     2
    % 1     2     1
    % 1     1     2

unique_perms = unique(all_perms, 'rows')
    % unique_perms =

    % 1     1     2
    % 1     2     1
    % 2     1     1
```

but this will generate **all** `N!` permutations, instead of just the `N! / (N_1! * N_2! * ... * N_M!)`. For `N = 3`, this doesn't affect much neither the memory consumption nor the timing, but as `N` increases and the number of unique elements decreases, the difference can be huge. So:

**Is there a (hopefully built-in) way to list all the unique permutations of an array containing non distinct objects, without intermediately keeping *all* permutations?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is code suggested in 2014 by [Bruno Luong](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/164470#921205) for this problem:

```
function p = uperm(a)
[u, ~, J] = unique(a);
p = u(up(J, length(a)));
end % uperm

function p = up(J, n)
ktab = histc(J,1:max(J));
l = n;
p = zeros(1, n);
s = 1;
for i=1:length(ktab)
    k = ktab(i);
    c = nchoosek(1:l, k);
    m = size(c,1);
    [t, ~] = find(~p.');
    t = reshape(t, [], s);
    c = t(c,:)';
    s = s*m;
    r = repmat((1:s)',[1 k]);
    q = accumarray([r(:) c(:)], i, [s n]);
    p = repmat(p, [m 1]) + q;
    l = l - k;
end
end
```

The above can be further improved by replacing `nchoosek` with one of [Jan Simon's functions](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?term=permutations+author%3AJan+author%3ASimon).

Comment: Nice! It is indeed faster than the other method. I looked at that thread but I must have overlooked this solution. Unfortunately I can't compile the nchoosek replacement function, but this will make a better thread on AskUbuntu :)